# Filter text in JTextPane

Tags: java, oop, tail

I am learning java (just finished reading of Head First Java book) and I've started to write app (for mine and learning purposes), which would read log file and changed fond of the line according to defined rules/filters.

I have some prototype, but now I am stuck with design ... coding is not a big deal but I still have problem to think in OOP and to create good design.

What I currently have are 3 classes.

```
public class App {
   //... contains main method, frame, button for file load, etc...
}

public class FileTail {
   //... open/read file, and create thread where file is checked for
   //changes and in case that file is changed, reads new lines
}

public class logText extends JTextPane {
   //... where the text -> file output appears
}
```

What I would like to do next, is to have other components on the frame, where I would say e.g.:

- filter out all lines which contains "INFO"
- lines which contains string "ERROR" will be red
- etc...

I cannot come up with design, like should I add this functionality to logText class? I know, that this is small app and probably everything could be in one class, but as one of the reasons is learning purpose, I would like to do it right.

I was thinking about create new class `patern`, which would contain searched `string`, `Font` and `Color`. Then in main class I would create `ArrayList<Patern>` and each before each new line is to be added to `JTextPane`, I would somehow search through `ArrayList<Patern>` for match.

Comment: This is probably a personal thing, but I'd probably be tempted to use a `JList` or `JTable` over a `JTextPane`.  The formatting for a `JTextPane` is done by the `StyledDocument`

Comment: I can do that, but even then I wold have the same question. I mean, formatting as such is not a problem in `JTextPane` (for example I can add new line which is going to have red color). What is more important for me is how to have "paper design". I can have more e.g. 10 filtering rules and I would like to not have all functionality in one class - which is probably wrong even in terms of future apps' extensions.

Comment: So what you really want is some kind "decorator", which supplied a block of (in this case) text, and a list of rules, would be able to generate the required formatting?

Comment: Exactly! And as I said, I could probably code all in one class, but I guess that is not the right OOP's attitude.

Comment: Okay, so you need some way for a "rule" to evaluate a "condition" (ie does the text contain "something") and then, when it evaluates to `true` you can apply some "format" to in some pre-defined way. This would allow rules to be combined (using and/or logic) which are then evaluated. So I guess, you need a `Rule` and a `Format` or `Condition` which is applied when the `Rule` evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a method that takes an argument of what ever you want to search for, and compares against a set of records, listing the records that records in some sort of list and returns the list.

good luck

Comment: Should this method be in new class along with filtering rules?

Comment: Assuming you are using object oriented programming, I would suggest you create a class defining all the properties of the objects you are planning to use, then go further make methods that can manipulate these objects, i don't believe you would need a new class with just methods to handle other objects as this may waste memory and force you to declare public, things which should be private. i suggest you use set and get methods while passing parameters of your filter criteria on the get methods. hope this works brother.

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of what I needed. I'll made some progress, but this helped me.